# socket() and sendto() dont return error codes when theres no internet connection

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, winsock2

Why does `socket()` not return `INVALID_SOCKET` when I have no internet connection? I thought it would fail and then I could exit my function. My function's error checking continues till `recvfrom()` and then just hangs when I have no internet connection. I thought that `socket()` or `sendto()` would return an error code when I have no internet connection but they are not. I am trying to rely on their failure as a sign the user has no internet connection and exit my function but thats just not working for some weird reason.

```
void myFunc()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("myipaddress");
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(123);

    // Doesn't fail when there's no internet connection
    protoent *proto = getprotobyname("udp");
    int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, proto->p_proto);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Doesn't fail when there's no internet connection
    char msg[48] = { 0x08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int iResult = sendto(s, msg, sizeof(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Hangs when there's no internet connection
    memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    socklen_t saddr_l = sizeof(saddr);
    iResult = recvfrom(s, msg, 48, 0, &saddr, &saddr_l);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        goto Cleanup;
    }

Cleanup:
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: A style issue -- you could get rid of those `goto Cleanup;` calls by utilizing RAII techniques, where the cleanup would happen automatically once the function returns.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah but that assumes the user of `myFunc()` will always be considerate enough/remember to cleanup after using the function.

Comment: How would you define "no internet connection"? Note you are using datagram sockets which are by definition not reliable.

Comment: @Merl -- Do you know what RAII is?  There is no need for the user to be considerate.  The cleanup is guaranteed no matter the reason for the exit of the function.  Ignoring the syntax errors, [See this](http://rextester.com/ISIS33492).  The magic of deterministic destructors in C++ makes this possible.  If now in the future, another return point is specified, or if you add functions that can potentially `throw`, the cleanup is guaranteed.

Comment: Hmm, what it *myipaddr*? If it is your own local IP address, it is reachable as soon as your network interface is up, even without any cable plugged in... You'd rather try to establish a TCP port 80 connection to www.google.com (or even better to your ISP site).

Comment: just use a timed wait mechanism (select, epoll, ...) on recvfrom()

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no requirement for sockets to be connected to the internet. Many applications use sockets for inter-process communication on a single machine. Such applications can still run fine when there is no internet connection.

`sendto()` could arguably return an error code; it can (under certain situations, as demonstrated by the desktop notification about network connection status) know that the packet can never be delivered. However, UDP communication and `sendto()` make no guarantees about delivery whatsoever, and apparently the implementation you are using does not consider the lack of connection worthy of an error code. Arguably this is a quality of implementation issue.

`recvfrom()` simply waits as long as you have specified (possibly indefinitely) for a message, but never receives one. Again, this is within spec, and again it could be considered a quality of implementation issue whether or not this particular situation is flagged or not.

Comment: "it should know" How exactly? Can you propose a mechanism?

Comment: Isn't that obvious? Once you specify an address, it is clear if it is an address on the local machine or not. If there is no network connection (a situation that is detectable; at least my machine tells me immediately if I pull the network cable) it becomes undeliverable.

Comment: (1) Network cable != internet connection (2) no network cable != undeliverable packets (off the top of my head, you may run a virtual machine and only the VM's custom kernel module knows which packets are deliverable to it).

Comment: You are right, but the fact is that the OS _does_ detect network failure in certain situations, and could at least return the proper error codes when it does. That doesn't make it 100% reliable, but as I already stated in the answer, there are no reliability guarantees of any kind anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the linux man page for sendto (assuming that all relevant the implementations are sufficiently similar to the berkley sockets baseline) here:

http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto

The documentation does not mention reporting and error if the network stack 'knows' that the message is undeliverable. This is reasonable, since the socket's transport may well not be IP4 or IP6. It could be any transport we chose to write a driver for: packet radio, serial cables or carrier-pigeons (if we could figure out the hardware for loading the printed messages into their satchels).

The only reference to possible errors from the transport is here:

> These are some standard errors generated by the socket layer. Additional errors may be generated and returned from the underlying protocol modules; **see their respective manual pages**.

As mentioned by others, UDP is an unreliable datagram protocol. Unreliability is expected. Non-delivery of a message is expected. Therefore not really an error. There would be little incentive for a protocol-layer author to code for handling transport errors - since they too are expected and not an error in the context of this protocol.

When a socket is opened over TCP, then lack of socket continuity is an error. If the transport reports that packet delivery is not possible (for a sufficiently long time) then this is an error condition in the protocol.